# Django ORM - query depending on through table

Tags: django, orm, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

here is my data model:

```
class User(Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through=UserTeam, related_name='users')

class Team(Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserTeam(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_special = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When i query for all users, i get a result like this (json result in rest api:

```
{
    'name': 'user-1',
    'teams': [
        {
            'name': 'team-1',
        },
        {
            'name': 'team-2',
        }
    ]
}
```

What i want to achieve is, i want to get only the the teams where the is_special flag is set to true for the user and team.

e.g. When a user is in two teams and one team has *is_special* flag set to false, then this team should be excluded from the result above...

Thats why i included in my user serializer:

```
teams = TeamSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

def get_teams(self, obj):
    teams = Team.objects.filter(
        userteam__user=self.context['request'].user,
        userteam__is_special=True
    )
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=teams, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

But i still get the same result...
any ideas or suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get more success approaching this from the through table.

I haven't tested this, and it's not optimal performance, but:

```
teams = TeamSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

...

def get_teams(self, obj):
    user_teams = UserTeam.objects.filter(
         user=self.context['request'].user,
         is_special=True
    )
    teams = [ut.team for ut in user_teams] 
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=teams, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Or, trying to pull a bit less from the DB:

```
def get_teams(self, obj):

    team_ids = UserTeam.objects.filter(
         user=self.context['request'].user,
         is_special=True
    ).values_list('team_id', flat=True)

    teams = Team.objects.filter(id__in=team_ids) 

    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=teams, many=True)

    return serializer.data
```